# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'. angular for using Promise

Tags: angular

I am practicing `Promise` with angular and I am getting the following error:

`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.`

[image]

Model

[image]

HTML

[image]

service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {IEmployee} from "./model/IEmployee";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeServiceService {

    //A Promise handles a single event when an async operation completes or fails.
    //An Observable is like a Stream (in many languages) and allows to pass zero or more events where the callback is called for each event.

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getEmployees(empCode: string):Promise<IEmployee> {
            return this.http.get('assets/example.json').map((res: Response) => <IEmployee> res.json())
                .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee>response.json())
                .toPromise()
                .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
    }

    //this is a simple way to handle errors
    handlePromiseError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        throw(error);
    }
}
```

-------------Update 1----------

I added the following import to the service:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Error:

```
Type 'ResponseType' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
        Type '"cors"' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
ERROR in
```

`/Users/drew/Desktop/Tutorials/UsingPromisingInsteadOfObserables/src/app/em
 ployee/employee-service.service.ts (15,80): Type 'Promise<any>' cannot be 
 converted to type 'IEmployee'.`

------------------------Update 2----------------------

New implementation in the service.

```
 constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getEmployees(empCode: string): Promise<IEmployee> {
        return new Promise<IEmployee>((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch('assets/example.json')
                .then(val => {
                    let r = val.json();
                    r
                        .then(v => { console.log(v) })
                        .catch(error => { console.log('error', error) })
                }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('request fail', err);
            })
        });
    }
```

Error:

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

Comment: Adding the employee service code may help

Comment: @Z.Bagley see updated post

Comment: You're duplicating a map: .map((res: Response) => <IEmployee> res.json())
                .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee>response.json()).

Comment: @Drew1208 posted my answer try like this. hope it will be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `map` duplicated in response when the fetch callback after the first `json()`.

**modiefied**

```
getEmployees(empCode: string):Promise<IEmployee> {
    return this.http.get('assets/example.json')
            .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee>response.json())
            .toPromise()
            .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
}
```

`httpclient` in  `angular` is implement `rxjs` basically.It not be use promise or map, just set subscribe and you could got the data what you request.

**rxjs**

```
this.http.get('assets/example.json').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  this.results = data['results'];
});
```

that `http` go.

**use fetch**

```
fetch('assets/example.json')
  .then(val => {
    let r = val.json();
    r
      .then(v => { console.log(v) })
      .catch(error => { console.log('get data fail', error) })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('request fail', err);
  })
```

Comment: The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly. Good catch, I am just frustrated.

Comment: @Drew1208 ummm , you could set the type `Observable<any>` to implict

Comment: I am using `promise` please see the git repo

Comment: your `IEmployee.ts` is blank.

Comment: It's really wired that you use observable and trans back to promise even result is shown.
If you want to use Promise , skip the `this.http` and use native javascript `fetch` as well.See the following of the code in my edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158654/discussion-between-rach-chen-and-drew1208).

Comment: Error: No provider for Http!, Please see updated post.

Answer (score 1):

All i had to do was to add a missing `import` statement

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**service.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { IEmployee } from './';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    getEmployees(empCode: string): Promise<IEmployee> {
        return new Promise<IEmployee>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('assets/json/sample.json')
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    resolve(<IEmployee>res.json())
                })
                .toPromise()
                .catch((error: Response) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { IEmployee, HomeService } from './';

export class Component {

    constructor(private homeService: HomeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.homeService.getEmployees("username")
            .then(data => {
                console.log('data', data);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Type 'Promise<any>' cannot be converted to type 'IEmployee'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'Promise<any>'.

Comment: Check your promise declared Change Promise<IEmployer> instead of any

Comment: you don't declare Promise<any> change it Promise<IEmployee> instead of  Promise<any>.